Performance Issues with Umbraco 13.5.1 and Azure SQL Database
I'm experiencing some performance bottlenecks in a web application using Umbraco CMS, currently on version 13.5.1 (though the issue has been observed across several subversions). Specifically, when utilizing Umbraco's _contentService to create or edit nodes, there are significant performance differences between different database setups.
`
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();

var isSaved = false;
if (!isToPublish)
{

    isSaved = _contentService.Save(node).Success;
}
else
{
    isSaved = _contentService.SaveAndPublish(node).Success;
}

stopwatch.Stop();
var elapsed = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

`
When running the application locally with an SQL Server (in a Docker container), node creation takes approximately 300ms. However, when switching to an Azure SQL database (Tier S1), the same operation takes between 3 to 6 seconds. This performance degradation also occurs when using a physical SQL Server.

Local Server:


Azure Db:



It appears the performance drop is related to network latency or the database setup, as the issue only arises when using Umbraco with non-local databases.
I've experimented with different connection strings but haven't found any improvements.
`
"umbracoDbDSN": "Server=tcp:XXXX.database.windows.net,1433;Database=YYYYY;User ID=UUUU@IIIII;Password=TTTTTTTTTTTT;"
Or
"umbracoDbDSN": "Server=XXXX.database.windows.net,1433;Database=YYYYY;User ID=UUUU;Password=TTTTTTTTTTTT;",
`
Has anyone encountered similar issues with Umbraco and Azure SQL? Are there any recommendations for optimizing performance when using an Azure database?
I want to improve the performance of this operation, acknowledging that some performance loss due to network latency is expected. However, the current time increase is far greater than anticipated.

Minimum recommended level for Umbraco production sites is S2 I think. I'd expect S1 to be a bit slower on save/publish as that's reasonably DB intensive. If you up the instance to S2, does it make a big difference to your performance numbers?
That said, the latency you're seeing is higher than I'd expect. Are the site and the DB in the same geographic region/all in Azure?
I'd also check if you've got any other code hooked into the save and publish event handlers, and finally, check your Examine setup, as that can be slower in Azure if not configured correctly, but again I'd not expect the big drop you're seeing.
